# How to SUM remainder in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner of Javascript and  trying to solve a problem in Javascript https://onlinejudge.org/external/116/11689.pdf
How can I sum the remainder in for loop?

Here is the code that I came to so far...

```
function pant(e, f, c) {
    let t=2;
    for(let i=0;i<t;i++){
        let pant=e+f;
        let buy=pant/c;
        let buy2=buy/c;

        //total bottles
        let total=buy+buy2;
        let rem=total%c;
        console.log(rem);

        return total;     
    }}
```

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71984790/13658816) by [uingtea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082344/uingtea) is very accurate and uses the `while` loop. The same may be achieved by using recursion as shown below.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// given "curr" number of caps and "cost" of each soda
// return number of sodas that can be purchased
const recurseCalc = (curr, cost) => {
  // number of sodas is "curr" / "cost" (rounded to lower integer)
  const numOfSodas = Math.floor(curr/cost);
  // remaining caps is "curr" less caps paid to obtain "numOfSodas"
  const remainingCaps = curr - (numOfSodas * cost);
  // console-log to help understand each recursion
  console.log(
    'curr: ', curr,
    'cost: ', cost,
    'num: ', numOfSodas,
    'rem: ', remainingCaps,
    'curr >= cost: ', curr >= cost ? 'yes' : 'no'
  );
  // if "curr" caps is more than "cost" of a soda
  // then, recursively calculate number of sodas
  // else, zero sodas can be purchased (since "curr" is lower than "cost")
  return (
    curr >= cost
      ? numOfSodas + recurseCalc(
        numOfSodas + remainingCaps,
        cost
      )
      : 0
  );
};

// use recursively calculate number of sodas
// for total caps (ie, "e" + "f")
const howManySodas = (e, f, c) => recurseCalc(e + f, c);

console.log('result\t---->| e: 9, f: 0, c: 3, sodas: ', howManySodas(9, 0, 3), ' |<---');
console.log('result\t---->| e: 5, f: 5, c: 2, sodas: ', howManySodas(5, 5, 2), ' |<---');
console.log('result\t---->| e: 7, f: 3, c: 3, sodas: ', howManySodas(7, 3, 3), ' |<---');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added in the snippet above.

Answer (score 2):

you need `while` loop and `parseInt`

```js
function pant(e, f, c) {
  let testNumber = `${e} ${f} ${c}`,
    result = 0
    
  e += f;
  while (e >= c) {
    result += parseInt(e / c)
    e = e % c + parseInt(e / c)
  }
  console.log(`result for ${testNumber}: ${result}`)
}

pant(9, 0, 3)
pant(5, 5, 2)
```

Comment: @Chiroru  please mark the answer as correct if it solve the problem